# django models relationship how to link a models A twice to model B

Tags: django, django-models

Let say i'm implementing a messaging service using django so i have 2 models
1 for messages and the second for users.
A message sender is a user's model instance and the message receiver also is a user's model instance.
is it a right way to do like this ?

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='', null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='', null=True)

class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User)
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)
```

Thanks

Comment: Apart from the fact you'll need add a related_name to the foreign keys - which Django will tell you when you try to run it - this looks fine. What's your question?

Comment: @lansanalsm Yes, its the right way, just add related_name in fields of Message table to make it easier to figure out sender and receiver of a message. You can read more here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, although you will need to change the `related_name`, since now this will error because there are two (implicit) relations from a `User` to `Message`s, furthermore you will need to specify what to do in case the `sender` and `receiver` are removed (you can remove the related messages as well, by specifying `models.CASCADE`, or [another strategy [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete)):

```
class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='sent_messages'
    )
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='received_messages'
    )
    message = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Thanks @Willem Van Onsem